# In a formulation of the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was wondering if a I could prove the following claim.

Let $a>0$ be a constant value. Consider the interval $[-a,a]$, and the function $f\in\mathcal{C}^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ yielding $f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow x=0$, for every $x\in[-a,a]$, there exists $c\in[-a,a]$ such that

\begin{equation*}
 f'( c)x=f(x).
\end{equation*}

---

My attempt to prove it is as follows. For every $x\in[0,a]$, applying the mean value theorem for $f$ in the interval $[0,x]$, there exists $c_x^+$ such that
\begin{equation*}
f'(c_x^+ )=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}.
\end{equation*}
Thus, $f(x)=f'(c_x^+ )x$. The case in which $x\in[-a,0]$ is parallel. Hence, for every $x\in[-a,a]$, there exists $c\in[-a,a]$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 f'( c)x=f(x).
\end{equation*}

---

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May want to do the $x = 0$ case separately as otherwise $f(x)/x$ is not very well defined, but it is a trivial case. Other than that it seems correct, although you might want to note where $c_x^+$ and $c_x^-$ lie for clarity.